# C# How Do I Load an image into a code-behind generated table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I'm using asp.net/c# to create a PDF file that will be downloaded. It's all done in the code behind by creating a series of HTMLTables that load into a div-created HTMLGenericControl.  This div is then converted into a string and passed into the function that generates the PDF file.  Below is a code sample:

```
//This dataset contains the student's name, age and grade, want it for all sections
List<studentExportPersonal> lsep = sp.getExportPersonal(exportStudents);

//Page Header containg Grade, Student Name, and Age
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

foreach (studentExportPersonal sep in lsep)
{
    foreach (string sec in secs)
    {
        HtmlTable identityTable = new HtmlTable();
        div.Controls.Add(identityTable);

        identityTable.Width = "100%";
        identityTable.Border = 0;
        identityTable.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "20px");

        HtmlTableRow identityTR = new HtmlTableRow();
        identityTable.Rows.Add(identityTR);

        HtmlTableCell tdGrade = new HtmlTableCell();
        identityTR.Cells.Add(tdGrade);
        tdGrade.Style.Add("font-size", "30px");
        tdGrade.Align = "center";
        tdGrade.RowSpan = 2;
        tdGrade.InnerText = sep.si.studentGrade;

        HtmlTableCell tdStudentName = new HtmlTableCell();
        identityTR.Cells.Add(tdStudentName);
        tdStudentName.Style.Add("font-size", "30px");
        tdStudentName.Align = "center";
        tdStudentName.InnerText = sep.si.studentName;

        HtmlTableCell tdStudentAge = new HtmlTableCell();
        identityTR.Cells.Add(tdStudentAge);
        tdStudentAge.Style.Add("font-size", "30px");
        tdStudentAge.Align = "center";
        tdStudentAge.RowSpan = 2;
        tdStudentAge.InnerText = sep.si.studentAge + " Years Old";

        HtmlTableRow identityTR1 = new HtmlTableRow();
        identityTable.Rows.Add(identityTR1);

        HtmlTableCell tdPic = new HtmlTableCell();
        identityTR1.Cells.Add(tdPic);

        Bitmap studPic;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
            studPic = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\studentPics\" + sep.si.studentPicID, true);
        else
            studPic = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"E:\Website\Cascade\studentPics\" + sep.si.studentPicID, true);
    }
}

export dmc = new export();

var sb = new StringBuilder();
div.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)));
string s = sb.ToString();

dmc.exportPDF("Student Profiles", "Portrait", s);
```

At the bottom of the foreach loop you can see that I'm creating a bitmap variable, my question is, how do I load it into the HTMLTableCell variable?

Comment: Why not use CSS for this? Also, I noticed you are referencing hard coded string paths to local files, the images will not appear when the application is deployed.

Comment: Thanks for that...I guess that's the type of stuff I'm trying to figure out...but that's also why I'm not using CSS...since everything is happening in the code behind, the tables are processed before hitting the .aspx so the css never has a chance to come into play...

Comment: Is it a unique image for each cell, or one commonly used? If it's a unique image each cell, we can take a closer look at your logic. If common, then CSS is perfect for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an image to a Cell just as you would add a Cell to a Row.

```
HtmlImage image = new HtmlImage();
image.Src ="/studentPics/" + sep.si.studentPicID;
tdPic.Controls.Add(image);
```

However as I look at your code, a GridView would be a better choice I think.
You can bind a List directly to the GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = lsep;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: HtmlImage -- PERFECT!!  Just to give a little more detail, I work for a school system and this is to allow teachers to pic students in their class and print out their profiles.  The student's picture ID is stored in the database, so after they select their students I read the IDs from the database, so it's a dynamic list of IDs.  But the HtmlImage works beautifully. Thanks again!!

Comment: Is the image stored in the database, or is the path of the image stored in the database, if it is the first then you need to convert the image to base64 first before displaying it in the table.